# JWT Bearer token authentication error after moving from ASP.NET vNext beta5 to beta7

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, jwt

I moved from beta5 to beta7 ASP.NET vNext and I get following error when I try to access protected API controller with invalid JWT token or without token at all:

> InvalidOperationException: The following authentication scheme was not
>   accepted:
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Authentication.Internal.DefaultAuthenticationManager.d__10.MoveNext()

If I try to access protected controller with valid token I can successfully get response.

Here is my protected controller:

```
[Authorize]
    [Route("api/protected")]
    public class ProtectedController : Controller
    {
        [Route("")]
        public IEnumerable<object> Get()
        {
            var identity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;

            return identity.Claims.Select(c => new
            {
                Type = c.Type,
                Value = c.Value
            });
        }
    }
```

Here is my Startup class:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
        }

        public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // Configure is called after ConfigureServices is called.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IApplicationEnvironment env)
        {
            ConfigureOAuthTokenConsumption(app);
            app.UseMiddleware<StaticFileMiddleware>(new StaticFileOptions());
            app.UseErrorPage();
            app.UseMvc(); 
        }

        private void ConfigureOAuthTokenConsumption(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {

            // Api controllers with an [Authorize] attribute will be validated with JWT
            app.UseOwin(addToPipeline =>
            {
                addToPipeline(next =>
                {
                    var appBuilder = new AppBuilder();
                    appBuilder.Properties["builder.DefaultApp"] = next;

                    var issuer = Settings.Issuer;
                    var audience = Settings.Audience;
                    var secret = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(Settings.Secret);


                    appBuilder.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
                        new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
                        {
                            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                            AllowedAudiences = new[] { audience },
                            IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
                            {
                                new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, secret)
                            },
                        });

                    return appBuilder.Build<AppFunc>();
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

When I was on beta5 it worked ok. I got 401 response when I requested protected controller without valid token and it was correct behavior. 
Do I need to change JWT token consumption configuration in ASP.NET vNext beta7?

Comment: I'm really curious: why using Katana's OAuth2/JWT bearer authentication middleware when you can use ASP.NET 5's one? https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.OAuthBearer/1.0.0-beta7

Comment: @Pinpoint, I tried consuming token with             app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(options => {
                options.AutomaticAuthentication = true;
                options.Audience = audience;
                options.TokenValidationParameters.IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(secret);
            }); but I get error 'System.InvalidOperationException: IDX10636: SignatureProviderFactory.CreateForVerifying returned null for key: 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey'. It's also not clear to me where to set issuer in this case.

Comment: Yes, symmetric keys are not yet supported. That said, you should really consider using an asymmetric key since it offers a much more robust approach. To set the issuer, simply use `options.Issuer = "issuer"`.

Comment: @Pinpoint, I can see there is only options.ClaimsIssuer, no options.Issuer. Is this what I need to set?

Comment: Woops, sorry, it's `options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuer`.

Answer (score 2):

I tested the code and what I see is that JWT tokens work fine without
`[Authorize]` attribute. So on the Controller level User is Authenticated and Claims are there.

There is another problem related to CORS setup as calling the site through Postman works fine but when I access it from different domain, I have

> The following authentication scheme was not accepted:

error even if I pass valid token.
Same story with `AuthorizationFilterAttribute` - user is always not authenticated in the filter but ok in the action.

By now the only workaround that I found is to add `ActionFilterAttribute` and check permission before action execute

```
   public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {

            var principal = context.HttpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;

            if (!principal.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                context.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
            }


            base.OnActionExecuting(context);
        }
```

Here user is Authenticated (if JWT present and valid), we don't have exceptions and can deny request.